# Abstract classes and Pod::Coverage

Tags: perl, code-coverage, perl-pod, dist-zilla

I've recently started to try to use `Dist::Zilla` for maintaining `Path::Class`.  I added the `[PodCoverageTests]` plugin, and it's reporting some failures in the `Path::Class::Entity` class, which is the abstract base class for `Path::Class::File` and `Path::Class::Dir`.

What I'd like is some way to tell the testing code that `Entity` doesn't need docs, but its two derived classes do - even though the methods are only defined in the parent class.  Anyone know some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Dist::Zilla's standard POD coverage test uses [Pod::Coverage::TrustPod](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pod%3a%3aCoverage%3a%3aTrustPod).

You should be able to say

```
=for Pod::Coverage
.
```

to tell it to assume that everything is documented.